# why Clipped gradient can get stuck in a flat spot

Tags: gradient-descent

I read the paper [Towards Evaluating the Robustness of Neural Networks by Carlini](https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.04644)

there is a phrase:
`the algorithm Clipped gradient can get stuck in a flat spot where it has increased some component x_i to be substantially larger than the maximum allowed`

I don't understand, why Clipped gradient can get stuck in a flat spot?

The full context, page 7:

> $$ x + δ \in [0,1]^n $$
>   2) **Clipped gradient** descent does not clip `x_i` on each iteration;
>   rather, it incorporates the clipping into the objective function to be
>   minimized. In other words, we replace `f(x + δ)` with `f(min(max(x + δ, 0), 1))`, with the min and max taken component-wise. While solving the
>   main issue with projected gradient descent, clipping introduces a new
>   problem: the algorithm can get stuck in a flat spot where it has
>   increased some component `x_i` to be substantially larger than the
>   maximum allowed. When this happens, the partial derivative becomes
>   zero, so even if some improvement is possible by later reducing `x_i` ,
>   gradient descent has no way to detect this.

Answer (score 1):

I think it means the following: denote some component of the gradient $[\nabla f]_i=\partial_i f$, and consider the situation mentioned for some $x$, where $x_i>>1$. Then, consider the partial derivative:
$$
\partial_i f(x)\approx\frac{f(x+\Delta)-f(x)}{\Delta_i}=\frac{f(x)-f(x)}{\Delta_i} = 0
$$
where $\Delta=(0,\ldots,0,\Delta_i,0,\ldots,0)$ and the second equality is because $\Delta_i$ is small, so $$ f(x+\Delta)=f(\min(\max(x+\Delta,0),1))=f(x_1,\ldots,x_{i-1},1,\ldots,x_n)=f(x) $$
This means that the algorithm will simply get stuck there (for that dimension), since that component of the gradient will stay at $0$.